# java.util.concurrent

Tags: java, websphere, executorservice, commonj

im trying to kick off a Runnable classes run method however i keep getting a NullPointerException,  Im using WebSpheres commonj.workmanager to get an instance of executorService.this is the code im using.

```
executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Inside run ()method..");
    }
});

ANY IDEAS?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you checking whether `executorService` is null before calling `execute()`? If not, it sounds like you need to check the WebSphere docs.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the reply, its the `executorService` that is `null`. Im using Spring to inject the property.

Comment: This information is better added as an edit to the question instead of an another answer.